# What database tables structure do bitcoin uses?

Tags: database

What databases do bitcoin core (nodes) uses? And how looks tables structure? I can't find it anywhere...

Comment: LevelDB and BerkeleyDB?

Comment: BDB is not used for storing block chain data and is included for historical reasons.

Answer (score 4):

There simply is none. There's a key value store in LevelDB for the UTXO, and for miscellaneous things like the locations of block files on disk. Relational databses are far too slow for the task, and unnecessary given the type of information being stored.